# Kivy Buttons Won't Stay Put During Window Resizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, 2d, kivy

I'm using kivy 1.10 and Python to make a game.

I want to have the buttons in my program keep their relative positions when the window is resized. I know I could do this if I could get the specific height/width of the screen. However, I don't know how to get that information after the program is resized. It seems like kivy might have some even easier way to make the buttons stay put.

How do I make the buttons stay where they are when the window is resized?

If possible, please tell me how to do this in python, not with the kivy language, as I'd prefer to try and stay away from that.

```
"""
Python 3.6.4
Kivy 1.10.0

Combines various .py files and
allows the game to run.
"""

__author__ = "RidiculousName"
__date__ = "Jan. 2018"

import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout



class MainMenu(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # declares widget buttons
    start_button = Button(pos=(25, 75),
                          background_normal="Images\\Start.png",
                          background_down="Images\\Start_Down.png",
                          size_hint=(.1, .1))

    load_button = Button(pos=(225, 75),
                         background_normal="Images\\Load.png",
                         background_down="Images\\Load_Down.png",
                         size_hint=(.1, .1))

    options_button = Button(pos=(425, 75),
                            background_normal="Images\\Options.png",
                            background_down="Images\\Options_Down.png",
                            size_hint=(.15, .1))

    quit_button = Button(pos=(708, 75),
                         background_normal="Images\\Quit.png",
                         background_down="Images\\Quit_Down.png",
                         size_hint=(.1, .1))
    quit_button.bind(on_press=sys.exit)

    background = Image(source="Images\\Main_Menu.png",
                       pos=(0, 0))

    # Adds widgets in order
    self.add_widget(background)
    self.add_widget(start_button)
    self.add_widget(load_button)
    self.add_widget(options_button)
    self.add_widget(quit_button)

class BanditKing(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Bandit King"
        self.icon = "Window_Icon.png"
        return MainMenu()

def main():
    Config.set("graphics", "width", "1600")
    Config.set("graphics", "height", "900")
    Config.write()
    BanditKing().run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using size_hint in your App. Did you know there is also the pos_hint attribute as well?

Where you use pos, you can also use pos_hint instead:

ie

```
    start_button = Button(pos=(25, 75))
```

Assuming your window is 100 x 100, you can change the above fixed size to:

```
start_button = Button(pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.75})
```

And the should reassign their position accurately.

If the Buttons are a child of another layout, you will need the parent layout(s) to also use pos_hint and not pos if trying to keep them relative to the window.

Additionally, pos_hint works in tandem with size hint. Say I wanted a button on top of my screen where it stretched all the way across my screen but only 10% of the way down. You would write it something like this in the kv file:

```
 Button:
     size_hint: 1, .1
     pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .9}
```

or in the py file,

```
 Button(size_hint=(1, .1), pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'y': .9})
```

Assuming the Button has no parents, its width is equal to the windows width, its height is equal to .1 (or 10%) of the windows height.

So with its pos_hint, it will always start from the right of window (since 'x': 0 = very start of the windows width) and 90% up from the bottom of the window, where the 10% of the Button's height would start creating reaching there to the top of the window.